# Match Divs by class and check if they contain a class using Js

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check a div by class (`top`) if he has an other div with an other class(`bottom`) inside so that the function returns a true or false in an array.

```
<div class="top">
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
<div class="top"></div>
```

I tried this but It only told me if the `<div class="top">` contains the `<div class="bottom">` and not if the `<div class="top">` comes without the `<div class="bottom">`

```
if ($(".top").find(".bottom").length > 0){ 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the ".top"-div's without ".bottom" with the [`has`](http://api.jquery.com/has/)-method:

```js
$('.top').has('.bottom').css('background', '#bada55');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  top has bottom
  <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
<div class="top">top without bottom</div>
```